# rspec awkward syntax to test change count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an rspec test that looks like this:

```
describe 'on DELETE to :destroy' do
  before do
    expect { delete :destroy, id: 6 }.to change(ModelName, :count)
  end

  it { is_expected.to respond_with :success }
  it { is_expected.to render_template :destroy }
end
```

I find it awkward having the test on change count inside the `before` block, and I don't need to run it twice. I'm hoping to find a syntax something like this instead:

```
describe 'on DELETE to :destroy' do
  before do
    delete :destroy, id: 6
  end

  it { is_expected.to respond_with :success }
  it { is_expected.to render_template :destroy }
  it { is_expected.to change(ModelName, :count) }
end
```

However the third test gives me the following error:

```
expected #count to have changed, but was not given a block
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, you need to pass a block, e.g.:

`it { is_expected.to change { ModelName.count } }`

Comment: I get a similar error message with `it { is_expected.to change { ModelName.count } }` - `expected result to have changed, but was not given a block`